# Can I use a TeX primitive in a "before" and "after" macro? (and how?)

Tags: macros, environments, enumerate, enumitem, primitives

## The Question

Can I use a TeX primitive in a "before" and "after" macro? (and how?)

There are two questions that I found useful and related to my question, which sent me in the right direction: how to even ask this question!

- [What are the different kinds of boxes in (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-boxes-in-latex)
- [Why does LaTeX make a distinction between commands and environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/why-does-latex-make-a-distinction-between-commands-and-environments)
- [How to make a list of unbreakable items?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-make-a-list-of-unbreakable-items)
- [How to prevent pagebreak in description environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/how-to-prevent-pagebreak-in-description-environment)

## Example Situation

I am using a custom list setup with the `enumitem` package and I would like to use a primitive in the  variables below:

```
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\texttt{\arabic*.},resume,before={<HERE>}, after={<HERE>}}
```

I would like to put `\vbox{` in the `before={}` and `}` in the `after={}`, but obviously I cannot type `before={\vbox{}, after={}}`

Why would I want to do this? For example, I could want to put a box around each mother and daughter list item, such that they remain on the same page. Or maybe I would like to put  other primitives around my list environment just for kicks. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have a feeling this might be the usual [x-y problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). I think it would be helpful if you actually posted what you are trying to achieve with the `\vbox`.

Comment: @Peter Grill Alright, I added an example situation. I just want to know if there is a way to do this. I disagree with the x-y principle. Science does not need to be applied, rather can also be for the sake of knowing. See Gresham's Law (applied to science) and Vannevar Bush :)

Comment: Why not `before=\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}, after=\end{minipage}`?

Comment: @egreg Because `minipage` is not a TeX primitive, it is an environment.

Comment: @macmadness86 which of course is why you should use it as it is much less likely to break latex. You can use `\vbox\bgroup` and `\egroup` but they are not supported latex commands and things will go wrong if you do

Comment: So what? Why should you use a primitive? However, the whole outer `legal` environment would be enclosed in the vertical box, so *no* page break would be available.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question and trying to help me. You both are two of the most-skilled TeX gurus on the site. I would just like to know if it is possible, and if so, how I can do it. I have never seen it done, but it might prove useful someday for global changes e.g. `\fbox{}` around a list, or other things. A pure answer that addresses the question and not any particular problem would be great!

Comment: @macmadness86 For adding a frame there are `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`. Trying to do it with low level tools is likely to break many things.

Comment: @macmadness86 I told you how to do it in my comment use `vbox\bgroup` not `\vbox{`  and similarly `\egroup` not `}` then you can put it in your macro arguments without messing up brace matching. But to put `\fbox` around a list you should not do that you should use the `lrbox` environment which was explicitly added to latex for that example.

Comment: `enumitem` is already well "above" plain TeX, so I'm not sure what benefit there could possibly be from mixing in non-LaTeX code.  If you want to go for a so-called "pure" solution, why not skip LaTeX all together and work in (e)plain TeX?  Besides, `lrbox` is pretty low-level compared to `enumitem`....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot accept your answer as a comment, I am sure you know that. Thanks for your help! I would be happy to label this question as answered…

Comment: @egreg Actually, there is a problem with page breaks with embedded lists. If you would like I can provide an example of this. And to everybody, I appreciate the warnings about doing this. Despite the potential problems, sometimes in a bind one must do what has to do to get the output to look right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\vbox\bgroup
```

and

```
\egroup
```

to start the box without using `{}` so you can pass these constructs in `{}` delimited arguments, but they are not supported latex commands and things will go wrong if you do.

But this should not be necessary for example  to put `\fbox` around a list you should not do that you should use the `lrbox` environment which was explicitly added to latex for that example. (Or a package such as `framed` or `mdframed`)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to avoid using TeX primitives in higher-level LaTeX commands. Is it correct to assume that bgroup stands for begin group and egroup for end group?