# Making little spaces between the lines of the title

Tags: titles

I have few questions and i appreciate any help. In the code below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\author{  \textsc{Hussein Eid } \\ 
\textsc{Faculty of Science } \\
\textsc{ Cairo University} \\
\textsc{B.SC Degree in Mathematics}      }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{huge}
\textbf{ GEOMETRY OF MANIFOLDS AND DIFFERENTIAL FORMS}
\end{huge}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

how can I leave little spaces between the lines of the titles?!. Besides, why the name of the author does not appear after running?!. Here is a screenshot of the output 
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you use `\huge` instead of `\begin{huge}...\end{huge}` normale spacing will be restored.

Comment: Yes, this works. Can you tell me how i can make the first letter of each word in the title looks much bigger than the rest of the litters in the word ?!

Comment: I'm not sure how that's going to look, anyway you could specify a different font size for the first letters. Since your title is already `\huge` you would need to set the other letters to `\Large` and the first letters to `\huge` or alternatively use `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` for the first letters. Give it a try and see for yourself

Comment: it seems you are looking for caps and small caps.  if you enter this text with "normal" casing -- "Geometry of Manifolds ..." -- and add `\scshape` you should get the result you want.  (i'm not sure how `article` handles `\title`, but you're not using that.)  and, as other comments and the answer point out, you need to end a paragraph to make sure the baselines are appropriate.

Comment: How did you get the idea of using an environment for the font size? Did you read that somewhere? Where did you read it?

Comment: Anyway, i want the title looks much bigger @Johannes_B

Comment: Yeah, i understand. Maybe [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280) can help you. Or the answer by David.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `\huge` not `\begin{huge}` .. `\end{huge}`

(or leave a blank line before the `\end{huge}` You are ending the font size change before the end of the paragraph, so setting huge text on a normal baseline.

---

Ideally should *not* have any such font and size commands in the body of the document.

The markup should be

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\author{Hussein Eid\\ 
Faculty of Science\\
Cairo University \\
B.SC Degree in Mathematics}

\title{Geometry Of Manifolds And Differential Forms}

\begin{document}


\maketitle



\end{document}
```

and then if I understand your comment you want to use the `\textsc` caps and small caps style for both title and author, which can be specified separately in a documentclass or in the preamble.

Comment: Could you comment on (preferably by ways of showing a link) *why* this should be done?

Comment: @Matsmath I put the reason already. If the font size ends before the paragraph the paragraph will be broken into lines with a target basline being the normalsize baseline.

Comment: I might have been looking for something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/why-does-latex-make-a-distinction-between-commands-and-environments

Comment: @Matsmath oh but the enviornment/command distinction is not really an issue at all here. You would see the same problem with `{\huge the title}` the issue is where the size change ends, not whether an environment or command is used.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle . I have one more question: Can you tell me how i can make the first letter of each word in the title looks much bigger than the rest of the litters in the word ?!
The second question in asked above is still unanswered.

Comment: @user100256 oh I didn't notice the second question, I'll add something; you haven't told latex to make a title.